# Gmail App Script - Getting it functioning on the UI

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I'm trying to capture all the emails given the sender's email. I got this working in the app script's logger, but how do I translate this action to actual gmail's user interface?

```
function myFunction() {
  var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; // Get first thread in inbox
  var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // Get first message
  Logger.log(message.getFrom()); // Log from address of the message
  Logger.log(GmailApp.search(message.getFrom()));
}
```

So this is a simple function that's within the app script. I'm trying to follow this [Expense It example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) but instead of actually having a popup with a form, Id like to have a button and just search the email of the inbox. Also, the variable thread in the above example is the first inbox, it doesn't show the inbox of the intended open email.

I guess I have two issues:

1. How do I get it working on gmail's UI without a form similar to 'expense it' demo. just need an add on button for action only, not creating new forms.
2. How do I capture the message of selected email, not the first thread in inbox.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to deploy your app script as a web app and use it as an add-on in gmail.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/building this shows the whole deployment process.